Как установить ограничение на кол-во открываемых вкладок одного типа?
Как установить ограничение на кол-во открываемых вкладок одного типа? Есть где-то какая-то настройка системы или свойство? Искал по коду simple, multi - ничего не нашёл.

Есть возможность запретить открывать одну и ту же форму более одного раза.

На уровне кода в модуле Security сейчас есть свойства
forbidDuplicateForms ... = DATA BOOLEAN (UserRole) CHARWIDTH 10;
dataForbidDuplicateForms ... = DATA BOOLEAN (CustomUser) CHARWIDTH 10;

Первое для роли, второе для конкретного пользователя.

На пользовательском уровне эначения этих свойств можно изменить на форме Администрирование -> Политика безопасности:



